# If you're back's supposed to be straight, why do you need a nice chair at the computer?

Tags: productivity

I read the article on Coding Horror (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/investing-in-a-quality-programming-chair.html) about nice chairs, but it doesn't make sense to me. I've heard many times over that always you should keep your back straight, but that means that the back of the chair is basically irrelevant.

Are you supposed to have a nice chair simply because of its seat cushioning?

Comment: This is a very good question, if such issues were not this would be the norm: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ93F03p5OY Please unlock this question, it is very important.

Comment: @STTR I agree ergonomics are important considerations for computer usage, but it's not really a "how do I get this to work with my computer" question though, so I don't think it cuts the mustard. :)

Comment: I'm asking here because I have no idea where else this would fit in, but yet it's important for all programmers. I knew it'd get locked, but it's an important question for anyone who sits at the computer a lot.

Comment: @techie007 In ancient times, the workplace and interfaces were considered less important than the computer itself. This affects the performance and rare understanding now. But beyond that, it is a matter of human health working at a computer operator fatigue and thus its performance. The basis of this question is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to have a nice chair to help properly align and support the shape of your back when you're sitting "straight" up.

Your back is not straight, and is made up of different regions which require different support, the most common being the [Lumbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumbar) region.

Proper cushioning also considers airflow, and things like stain and microbe resistance.

Check out [Humanscale](http://www.humanscale.com/products/category_detail.cfm?category=seating) for some [excellent chair](http://www.humanscale.com/products/product_detail.cfm?group=FreedomTaskChairWithHeadrest) and [ergonomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_factors_and_ergonomics) accessory examples.

When used with a quality [adjustable keyboard and mouse tray](http://www.humanscale.com/products/product_detail.cfm?group=KeyboardSystems), and having it all [setup properly](http://www.thehumansolution.com/ergonomic-office-desk-chair-keyboard-height-calculator.html), it can eliminate and (more-so) prevent most related strain injuries.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are honestly linked in the post that you linked.  [Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/computer-workstation-ergonomics.html) and [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/03/a-developers-second-most-important-asset.html).  Honestly I've used a whole range of chairs and the best that I'd ever sat in were the Steelcase Think chairs we used to have in my old office...so last month I invested in one for use in my home.  They also last longer than every other chair I've had (which usually break/fail in some spectacular way)  I'm in this chair 12+ hours every day and it's the single most important investment I've ever made.

The next best investment was a [quality keyboard](http://elitekeyboards.com/products.php?sub=topre_keyboards,rftenkeyless&pid=rf_se1900) and training myself to use the mouse as little as possible.